# React: How to use inline styles in conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs

How do I handle the following:

```
const SpeedTest = ({ speed }) => (
  <div {speed > 80 ? {{style=color:red}} : {{style=color:green}} }>
    {speed > 80 ? "Too fast!" : "All fine"}
  </div>
);
```

Conditional text change works fine, but I am not able to get the color change done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this (remember to use quotes around inline styling values):

```
const SpeedTest = ({ speed }) => (
  <div style={{ color: speed > 80 ? 'red' : 'green' }}>
    {speed > 80 ? "Too fast!" : "All fine"}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: ah, I need to set the condition inside of the style declaration - that does the trick. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
const SpeedTest = ({ speed }) => (
  <div style={{ color: speed > 80 ? "red" : "green" }}>
    {speed > 80 ? "Too fast!" : "All fine"}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrected

```
const SpeedTest = ({ speed }) => (
  <div style={{color: speed>80 ?'red':'green'}}>
    {speed > 80 ? "Too fast!" : "All fine"}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can hold style in the variable and then change its value based on condition

```
  const SpeedTest = ({ speed }) => {
   let style={}
     if(speed>80){
        style={color:'red'}
     }else{
        style={color:'green'}
     }
    return (
      <div style={style}>
         {speed > 80 ? "Too fast!" : "All fine"}
     </div>
    )
   };
```

Comment: nice approach as well, thanks!